# What is the meaning of Gramp's word to Z?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, antz

In [Antz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120587/), what is the meaning of Gramp's words to Z?

> Gramps: You head towards the monolith.
>
> Gramps:**Ten clicks past** the great canyons to the land of **red and white**.

Ten clicks past means what? To my knowledge, **clicks** means mouse clicks.

I didn't get what **red and white** means.

Comment: I haven't seen the film so can't comment on the 'red and white' part of your question. But 'click' is likely a reference to the [Military usage of the word](https://www.reference.com/government-politics/far-military-terms-14518d922c35cfed)

Comment: Gramps is a Worker in the movie not soldier.

Comment: Then it could be a play on words? It does seem unlikely that he would be referring to mouse-clicks.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85009/why-does-klick-mean-kilometer-in-us-military-slang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Land of Red and White is a **picnic blanket** which they mistake for Insectopia

[image]

As for clicks it's a military term usually meaning **"[kilometers](https://www.reference.com/government-politics/far-military-terms-14518d922c35cfed)"** <sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* Thanks to @Longshanks for the link</sup>

Obviously, in this case it's probably not meant as *actual* kilometers but rather just to indicate that Gramps has military way of speaking.

There is a [**Wikia**](http://dreamworks.wikia.com/wiki/Drunk_Scout) which refers to him as a "Drunk Scout" so a military background seems reasonable.